# Save the output of for-loop as a list or tuple

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

How do I save the output of a for-loop as a list or tuple?

```
# finding prime numbers in given range
num_range = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print ("Below are the Prime Numbers")
for num in range(2,num_range+1):
#    print (num,"is taken as num")
    for i in range(2,num):
#        print (i, "is taken as i")
        if num % i == 0:
            break          
    else: 
        print (num)
```

Comment: Start with an empty list before the loop, then append to it inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In order to save the prime numbers,check the code below

```
num_range = int(input("Enter a number: "))
p_num = []
print ("Below are the Prime Numbers")
for num in range(2,num_range+1):
#    print (num,"is taken as num")
    for i in range(2,num):
#        print (i, "is taken as i")
        if num % i == 0:
            break          
    else:
        p_num.append(num)
        print (num)
```

print the numbers as and when you find OR print the list

`print p_num`

Comment: Thanks a lot, its worked for me with the below code as well(its similar  to your code.)   prime_list = []
def num_range():
        num_range = int(input("Enater a number: "))
        for num in range(2,num_range+1):
                for i in range(2,num):
                        if num % i == 0:
                                break
                else:
                        prime_list.append(num)
        return                        
num_range()
print(prime_list)